# Gateway timeout Django

Tags: python, django, iis

Have a Django website running on a virtual machine. When I run the site locally on a virtual machine via runserver, everything works as it should. But if I run with the condition runserver 0.0.0.0:8000 (to connect from another machine in the local corporate network), then when I run heavy queries on the site (with a runtime of more than a minute with access to the Postgres database), I get a Gateway Timeout error. But the request itself is not interrupted and continues its execution. I don't understand the reason.

I tried to adjust the SETTINGS by adding a TIMEOUT, and I started it from under IIS with an indication of a long TIMEOUT - the result is the same.

Comment: Gateway timeout is a very generic error, there is no specific cause for this, you need to debug the cause using [Network Monitor Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=4865), this tool will help you to identify the problem.